# Couchbase: syntax error. Not accepting NOT IN array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

**Problem Description**

I have the following query.

```
SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(META().id, ":"))[0] AS _id not in ["1-200101", "2-200101"]
FROM base
WHERE SUBSTR0(META().id, 0, 2) = "x:"
    AND code = "XXX"
    AND indexed_data.type = "Fire" 
    AND (indexed_data.link IS VALUED AND indexed_data.linkin ["3-200101"])
    AND (indexed_data.shared IS VALUED AND indexed_data.shared in ["4-200101"]) 
    LIMIT 998
```

Couchbase is not accepting `not in ["1-200101", "2-200101"]` I can't find a solution.

---

**Error**

```
  [
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at not",
    "query": "SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(META().id, \":\"))[0] AS _id not in [\"1-200101\", \"2-200101\"]\r\nFROM base\r\nWHERE SUBSTR0(META().id, 0, 2) = \"x:\"\r\n    AND code = \"XXX\"\r\n    AND indexed_data.type = \"Fire\" \r\n    AND (indexed_data.link IS VALUED AND indexed_data.linkin [\"3-200101\"])\r\n    AND (indexed_data.shared IS VALUED AND indexed_data.shared in [\"4-200101\"]) \r\n    LIMIT 998"
  }
]
```

Comment: I believe you can only use `IN` in a `WHERE` clause. Have you considered moving that down, like: `AND META().id IN ["1-200101", "2-200101"]` or probably even better `USE KEYS ["1-200101", "2-200101"]`

Comment: @MatthewGroves  what level should I put `USE KEYS`. Thank you so much for ur help

Comment: Yes I actually did the following `AND ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(META().id, ":"))[0] not in ["41EPT7ZZZZ_copy"]` It worked.

Comment: Check out the USE KEYS doc here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/hints.html#use-keys-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once aliased projection expression (AS _id) after that must have comma and another projection or FROM.

IN can be used any where expression is allowed

```
SELECT _id
FROM base
LET _id = SPLIT(META().id, ":")[-1]
WHERE META().id LIKE "x:%"
    AND code = "XXX"
    AND indexed_data.type = "Fire"
    AND indexed_data.link IN ["3-200101"]
    AND indexed_data.shared IN ["4-200101"]
    AND _id NOT IN ["1-200101", "2-200101"]
LIMIT 998
```

NOTE: f1 = 10 In predicate already implied  (f1 IS VALUED AND f1 = 10). Negative array subscript means index from the end.